# How many digits are in the decimal representation of $\frac{2^{2001}5^{1950}}{4^{27}}$?

Tags: exponentiation

My answer is 1950, but the answer sheet says 1949. I think the answer sheet is wrong.

> How many digits are in the value of the following expression: $(2^{2001}*5^{1950})/4^{27}$?

I solve this problem as following: $(2^{2001}*5^{1950})/4^{27}=(2*5)^{1950}*2^{51}/2^{54}=10^{1950}/8$, which give total digits of 1950.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{10^{1950}}{8} = 10^{1947}  \times \frac{1000}{8} = 125  \times  10^{1947}$, which is $125$ followed by $1947$ zeros, hence has $1950$ digits.

However, if we divide by $2$ only then would the answer would drop to $1949$ digits. So I think there is a mistake in the answer sheet. You are correct.

Comment: One more bug (or al least typo) in a textbook !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You should read Indian textbooks. They are the most uncompromising,especially M.L Khanna, Viraf Dalal etc. Only the cookery books are well written.

Comment: Is there any one I could read online ? Curious to see (if you give me a link). Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  I actually do not know how many of them are online. I have hard copies of all the above.  An ordinary search doesn't throw up the books I would have wanted you to read. Though, Sunita Arora could be online... no I can't find it immediately. I'll get back if I can find you some book. Though you will never thank me after reading it.